# URL Schemes iOS

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Can we launch our application through iphone message app using URL schemes.Launching of message app through our application is possible via URL schemes ,is it vice versa also? if yes please suggest how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a custom URL scheme in your app's property list then you could open your app via email or message by clicking the link sent within message or email.

Suppose you have customURL  defined in property list with `yourlink` it means that it will be working as  `yourlink://`

You can use `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` for composing a new message.

Answer (score 0):

check below link and you will find implementation of URL Schemes

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html